# How to manipulate pom.xml while creating project via archetype

Tags: maven-2

I'm making an archetype via the goal create-from-project and a propertyFile for webservice projets which using jaxws. Therefore I have to enter the service endpoint implementation into the configuration of the jaxws plugin.
My POM-Snippet:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>wsgen</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsgen</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sei>ws.ExampleWSBean</sei>
```

How can I manipulate the ws.ExampleWSBean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. After the creation of the archetype project via the command:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.properties=../archetype.properties
```

I modified the pom.xml in the archetype-resources. I only replaced the ws.ExampleWSBean against ${package}.ExampleWSBean.